# Como utilizar um pushbutton ligado no pino PC13 para ligar um LED externo no microcontrolador STM32-C031C6?

Tags: microcontrolador

Preciso ligar um LED externo através de um PUSHBUTTON ligado ao pino PC13 de um microcontrolador STM32 núcleo C031C6, não posso usar a biblioteca HAL e tenho que fazer isso somente com registradores, tentei de diversas formas e não consegui êxito em nenhuma delas, estou utilizando o simulador WOKWI.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.